# Is it bad practice to have two AsyncTask inner classes in one file?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In one `Activity`, I have 2 heavy tasks. One is a creation of the default database with default rows and values. The other one is fetching all data from the database to populate UI elements on the screen. There are over 100 UI elements on that page (statistical data).

Now, would it be bad to have two `AsyncTask` classes in one Java code file? One would be used to create default database (activated only on first start) and the other one would be used a lot of times to fetch all data from the database needed to populate the afore mentioned UI elements.

I am asking about bad practice and not about the fact whether the same `AsyncTask` class could be used for both heavy tasks (via `if/else`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Don't think so. How else would you do two background tasks ?

I would recommend however that for code clarity you use a design pattern whereby the result of the background tasks is differentiated in the same method using request codes that you send to the `AsyncTask`.

Something like:

```
new AsyncTask1(this, 0).execute();
new AsyncTask2(this, 1).execute();
```

The AsyncTask can then call back the same method in the `Activity` and you can differentiate on the basis of the request code.

```
onBackgroundTaskCompleted(int requestCode, Object result) {
    if (requestCode == 0 ) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
```

For an example of using this pattern using interface have a look at the async classes at : https://github.com/sfarooq/A-droid-lib/

Answer (score 1):

> A better way is Take out the AsyncTask and create a public class
>   wihich has 2 methods 1 for fetching and one for creating database..

This really has the Advantage of **OO** and also it reduces your code and seperates **UI from BackgroundTask**...

Answer (score 1):

I think It is ok to have more then one AsyncTask In on activity if they perform totally different task.